# In NextJS: how to get user information from session into getServerSideProps()?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm learning NextJS for the first time and got a little lost while trying to build a home page after the user logs in. I can't seem to either get the Session data to provide any information or to understand how to fill in the blanks from the different docs for NextAuth and NextJS.

I would like to not pass the user id in the query string and would prefer to use the session data to get the user info.

Here's my `pages/protected/index.tsx` file:

```
import SignOut from "@/components/sign-out";
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"
import React from "react";
import { InferGetServerSidePropsType, GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import Router from "next/router";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { Member, Tribe, User } from "@prisma/client";
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';

type Victor = (
  User & {members: (Member & {tribe: Tribe})[]}
);

// export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{victor: Victor}> = async () => {
//   const ses = await getSession();
//   const res = await prisma.user.findFirst({
//     include: {
//       members: {
//         include: {
//           tribe: true,
//         },
//       },
//     },
//     where: {
//       email: ses && ses.user && ses.user.email ? ses.user.email : '',
//     },
//   });
//   console.log(res);
//   return { props: {res}, };
// };

// export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // const ses = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);
  const ses = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  
  const victor = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    include: {
      members: {
        include: {
          tribe: true,
        },
      },
    },
    where: {
      email: ses && ses.user && ses.user.email ? ses.user.email : '',
    },
  });

  console.log('SESSION DATA', ses);

  return { props: { victor }};
}

export default function Home({
  victor,
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  console.log('PRINTING DATA', victor);
  return (
    <pre>...Data goes here...</pre>
  );
};
```

As you can probably infer from my file, I've tried several different methods I've seen to get data to pull in. From the NextAuth documentation, my current setup should work if I added a `context` variable to my `getServerSideProps()` function but I have zero clue where that variable comes from or how to import it.
I also have a feeling I'm missing something conceptually as to how the NextJS router works and where things should be placed in best practice. I've used NodeJS before but my primary background is PHP and PHP frameworks like Symfony, Wordpress, Codeigniter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS provides server-side rendering, static site generation, and client-side rendering. (https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/how-nextjs-works/rendering)

`getServerSideProps()` function runs server-side. so web server can pre-render the pages with returned props.

The `context` that comes in as a argument in `getServerSideProps()` contains `GET` request and response that the browser sends to receive the file (i.e. your page). If we use `getServerSession()`, NextAuth will get our session information based on the `jwt` stored in the browser's `cookies` which is contained the `GET` request.